# How to correctly scale integers between intervals?

Tags: c++, math, integer

I have `uint16_t` integers in the range `[ 0 .. 4092 ]` and I need to scale them into `[ 0 .. 255 ]` interval.

What’s the correct formula for that?

The obvious one `y = x * 255 / 4092` doesn’t work because the scaling factor is 15.988 so I need 15-16 (usually 16, rarely 15) input values mapped into every output value. With that formula the output 255 only produced for a single input value.

The less obvious formula, which uses an offset to round to nearest, `y = ( x * 255 + 2045 ) / 4092`, doesn’t work either because the output 255 corresponds to 9 input values `[ 4084 .. 4092 ]`, again that’s not what I want, I want 15 or 16 input numbers mapped into each output number.

BTW, I have gigabytes of these numbers in memory, for this reason I’d rather not use floating point math for this.

Comment: What does "_correct_" mean in your context? What properties should the mapping have? It seems like you are asking what your requirements ought to be.

Comment: @user17732522 I am guessing they mean the number of inputs that match to a given output is roughly the same for all outputs.

Comment: @user17732522 By correct I mean even split. I have 4093 possible inputs, and 256 outputs. The split ratio is ~15.98. This means every slice of 15-16 input numbers should be converted into the same output.

Comment: @Soonts But you don't care which values specifically are mapped 15 times and which are mapped 16 times?

Comment: Maybe try multiplying by 256 instead of 255 (or left shifting by 8).

Comment: @user16217248 If I multiply by 256, the formula won’t work at all because for 4092 input it will output 256, out of range.

Comment: @Soonts Then what about multiplying by 256 and dividing by 4093?

Comment: Replace calculation with a table?

Comment: @molbdnilo That would cost a lot of memory though.

Comment: @user16217248 I have a small C# project which produces a *.tsv table with two columns of all 4093 possible values, and your formula seems to actually work. Thanks.

Comment: @user16217248 4093 bytes is a lot?

Comment: @molbdnilo Certainly more than a couple of constants and a shift and division instruction.

Comment: @molbdnilo Not a lot of memory but still, math is faster than memory access. The answer I accepted is better. Take a look, when compiling for AVX2, it only took 7 arithmetic instructions to scale 8 numbers: https://godbolt.org/z/119r3PrMG

Comment: @molbdnilo And they asked for a formula. How would they make a lookup table without either spending hours populating it by hand or using the formula to populate it quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try multiplying and dividing by **one more** than you currently are. This code seems to produce your expected results:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4092; ++i)
        cout << (i<<8)/4093 << endl; // i<<8 is equivalent to i*256
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the formula. As for the implementation, I’ve optimized into a single AVX2 instruction to scale 16 numbers. The instruction is `_mm256_mulhi_epu16` which computes `(a*b)>>16` for two `uint16_t` numbers, the second argument is `( 256 << 16 ) / 4093`

Answer (score 3):

*I'm adding some theoretical background for the accepted answer.*

> With that formula the output 255 only produced for a single input value.

This gets you close to a solution. Let's be more specific, though. The highest output (255) is produced for only a single input value (the highest, specifically 4092). In other words, the formula works for every input value but one. If you were to drop 4092 from your input, you would consequentially drop 255 from your output and get an equitable distribution.

Use this to your advantage. Change the setup a little, and build-in the ability to drop the highest value. Change your formula to map the interval `[0, 4093]` to `[0, 256]`.

```cpp
y = x * 256 / 4093;
```

Now the output **256** is produced for only a single input value (**4093**) and otherwise the distribution is good. However, the input 4093 is assumed to never occur, so the output 256 is never produced. That is, you have mapped the (half-open) interval `[0, 4093)` to `[0, 256)` with values distributed as evenly as possible.

So the trick here was to think in terms of half-open intervals instead of closed intervals. There are other situations where this trick comes in handy; you might want to add it to your toolbox for dealing with integer math.

---

**WARNING:** The product of 4092 and 256 is a 24-bit value, and you are using 16-bit integers. This is not a problem as long as `int` is 32 bits (since the values are promoted to `int` for the calculation), but be aware of this caveat. If you were to run this code on a 16-bit system (or if you apply this solution to `uint32_t`), the calculation would overflow. While overflow is defined for unsigned integers, the result might differ from what you expect.